# cURL and RestClient - SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rest-client

I cannot access  to server through RestClient.

I have this code written in cURL (it sends XML file to server for parsing)

```
curl -T /Users/amok/Code/1188/dragon/test.xml --cert Users/amok/Code/1188/dragon/client_1188.pem --key Users/amok/Code/1188/dragon/client_1188.key -k -u 1188:aaa https://smart.com/index.cgi
```

Need to make the same in RestClient. I've tried this one, but it doesnt work.

```
return RestClient::Resource.new(
  'https://smart.com/index.cgi',
  :ssl_client_cert  =>  OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "/cert/client_1188.pem"))),
  :ssl_client_key   =>  OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "/cert/client_1188.key"))),
  :user => '1188', 
  :password => 'aaa'
).post(xml, :content_type => 'application/xml')
```

(xml is file, stored on server)

The problem is:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in BackOffice::DragonPilotController#create
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

The palm is on my face now... ((( Thank you

Comment: use PUT method instead of POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use PUT method instead of POST